# sed command in script function not working?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, function

I have an `sed` command line which replaces ASCII 1 with `|`:

```
sed -e 's/^A/\|/g' file_name
```

and this works. However, when I put it in a function in my bash file:

```
func(){
    sed -e 's/^A/\|/g'
}
```

it doesn't work:

```
func file_name
```

just hangs, instead of displaying the file.

Have I made a mistake? I opened a new terminal so my bash was definitely loaded.

Comment: You got your answer, but I'd like to add that you don't need to escape `|` with a backslash. It doesn't have a special meaning in the replacement string. The superfluous backslash will usually do no harm, but `\|` is undefined, so future versions of `sed` could give it some unwanted meaning.

Comment: @Philippos Quite insightful for such a subtlety. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to process `file_name` as an input parameter it doesn't just magically get applied to commands in the function...

```
func() {
    sed -e 's/^A/\|/g' "$1"
}
```

First parameter passed is stored in `$1`, second in `$2`, and so on.

This would work with your version, BTW: `func < file_name`

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't actually hang. It waits for input :-)

Either you do this

```
func() # replace something in the file, i.e. modify it
{
    sed -e 's/^A/\|/g' -i "$1"
}
```

or this

```
func() # output the contents of the file to console after applying sed
{
    sed -e 's/^A/\|/g' < "$1"
}
```

Also bash/POSIX shell are not C.